# Why my AJAX not appending the result when using two variables?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a report using AJAX to retrieve data. The variable is the date. When using a single date, the ajax works great and show expected output. However, when using two dates (date range) the ajax is not appending my output.

My AJAX with single date:

```
$("#tbl_list_brg tbody").on('click','.btn_report', function() { 

    $('.loading').show();       
    var var_tgl  = 'tgl='+tgl;

    $.ajax({
            type     : "POST",
            url      : "<?php echo site_url('con_atk/xxx'); ?>",
            async    : true,
            cache    : false,
            dataType : "json",
            data     : var_tgl,
            success  : function(data)
            {
                var tableData,t1,t2,t3,t4;

                var last    ="";
                var no      = 1;                    

                $.each(data.result_minta_by_date, function(index, rows_minta) {

                    if(last != rows_minta.NamaOutlet){ 
                        t1  = "<td rowspan='"+rows_minta.j_item+"' style='text-align:right; vertical-align:middle'>"+ no++ +"</td>";
                        t2  = "<td rowspan='"+rows_minta.j_item+"' style='text-align:left;  vertical-align:middle'><strong>";
                        t2 += (last == rows_minta.NamaOutlet ? "" : rows_minta.NamaOutlet)+"</strong></td>"; 
                    }
                    else{   t1  = ""; t2 = ""; }

                    t3  =     "<td class='barang' style='text-align:left; vertical-align:middle'>"+ rows_minta.NamaBarang +"</td>";

                    if(last != rows_minta.NamaOutlet){                          
                        t4   = "<td rowspan='"+rows_minta.j_item+"' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>";
                        t4  += rows_minta.tanggal_permintaan +"</td>";                      
                    }
                    else{   t4  = ""; }                     

                    tableData += "<tr>"+t1+t2+t3+t4+"</tr>";

                    $('#tbl_content tbody tr').remove();                        
                    $('#tbl_content tbody').append(tableData);                      
                    last = rows_minta.NamaOutlet;
                });                 
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('.loading').hide();
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
    });
});
```

My AJAX with two dates (Date Range) :

```
$("#tbl_list_brg tbody").on('click','.btn_report', function() { 

    $('.loading').show();       
    var var_range_tanggal   = "t1="+ tgl_dri +"&t2="+ tgl_smp;

    $.ajax({
            type     : "POST",
            url      : "<?php echo site_url('con_atk/xxx'); ?>",
            async    : true,
            cache    : false,
            dataType : "json",
            data     : var_range_tanggal,
            success  : function(data)
            {
                var tableData,t1,t2,t3,t4;

                var last    ="";
                var no      = 1;                    

                $.each(data.result_minta_by_date, function(index, rows_minta) {

                    if(last != rows_minta.NamaOutlet){ 
                        t1  = "<td rowspan='"+rows_minta.j_item+"' style='text-align:right; vertical-align:middle'>"+ no++ +"</td>";
                        t2  = "<td rowspan='"+rows_minta.j_item+"' style='text-align:left;  vertical-align:middle'><strong>";
                        t2 += (last == rows_minta.NamaOutlet ? "" : rows_minta.NamaOutlet)+"</strong></td>"; 
                    }
                    else{   t1  = ""; t2 = ""; }

                    t3  =     "<td class='barang' style='text-align:left; vertical-align:middle'>"+ rows_minta.NamaBarang +"</td>";

                    if(last != rows_minta.NamaOutlet){                          
                        t4   = "<td rowspan='"+rows_minta.j_item+"' style='text-align:center; vertical-align:middle'>";
                        t4  += rows_minta.tanggal_permintaan +"</td>";                      
                    }
                    else{   t4  = ""; }                     

                    tableData += "<tr>"+t1+t2+t3+t4+"</tr>";

                    $('#tbl_content tbody tr').remove();                        
                    $('#tbl_content tbody').append(tableData);                      
                    last = rows_minta.NamaOutlet;
                });                 
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('.loading').hide();
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
    });
});
```

Note:

- When I alert the data in both AJAX, the data exists.
- The second AJAX error is the loading is keep spinning and not showing the 
  modal
- In the second AJAX, If I remove the `.loading` the modal is not showing

**EDIT**

My Controller:

```
//REPORT PER PERMINTAAN
public function get_report_permintaan()
{      
    $tgl_minta  = $this->input->post('tgl');

    $t1         = $this->input->post('t1');
    $t2         = $this->input->post('t2');

    $data['response']   = 'false';  
    $q_barang           = $this->model_atk->get_report_per_minta_brg($tgl_minta,$t1,$t2);

    $data = array ('result_minta_by_date' => $q_barang);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: how is your data being returned? In form of json or just a plain html?

Comment: @Vincent1989 in JSON. I'll add my controller in the question

Comment: Is the `success` handler called at all in the second example?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes. I tried to alert the `tableData` and it contains the data, just not appending the rows. I wonder why

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are using JSON in that POST data, try to use https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ to serialize

Comment: First AJAX is working fine, but why the second AJAX fail to append the rows??

Comment: have you tried to decode json in your controller?, it seems you read it from post data directly

Comment: Yes. The data exist for both ajax in the controller and the view. But, the second AJAX did not append the rows only the first AJAX did.